# "invalid_client" error while trying to fetch token from Intuit API

Tags: php, curl, intuit-partner-platform

I'm using Curl/PHP to get the token to communicate with QuickBooks Intuit API.

I'm able to summon the following response (a JSON Text error):

> `{"error":"invalid_client"}`

This is how:

**Starting Page**

```
$parameters = array(
    'client_id' => "my client id",
    'scope' => "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting",
    'redirect_uri' => "http://localhost/redirect.php",
    'response_type' => "code",
    'state' => "RandomState"
);
$authorizationRequestUrl = 'https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?' . http_build_query($parameters);
header("Location: ".$authorizationRequestUrl);
```

**Redirect endpoint (page) fetching access token**

```
$queries = array();
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queries);

$client_id = "My Sandbox client id";
$client_secret = "My Sandbox secret";
$redirect_url = "http://localhost/redirect.php";
$access_token_url = "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer";
$scope = "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting openid profile email phone address";

$authorizationHeader = "Basic ".base64_encode($client_id.":".$client_secret);

$data = array(
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_url,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    "code" => $queries["code"]
);
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $access_token_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization" => $authorizationHeader,
        "Accept" => "application/json",
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Connection" => "keep-alive"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($response); # see JSON Text error above
```

How can I prevent the `invalid_client` error code with the QuickBooks Intuit API?

Comment: I believe you are missing `code` array key in `$data`. Check this out, https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/openid-connect, under "Request parameters for token exchange" section

Comment: Kindly check updated code.

Comment: Is the request working if you send a curl request from terminal/cmd with same creds?

Comment: I can confirm that Authorization code is coming in the first request successfully but the second request is not working as mentioned above.

Comment: Can you try using encoding the url for `$authorizationRequestUrl`. Oh hang on, so your auth request is going to https and redirect url is going to http, can you please maintain consistency?

Comment: What you are passing for CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER there, is wrong. Quote manual for curl_setopt, on that particular option: _"An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`"_

Comment: I think that is not correct. You may check the official docs here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0

Comment: I think @CBroe is correct. Could you quote the intuit docs that lead you to believe otherwise? Have you tried CBroe's suggestion on how you should format the headers?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the issue. I was missing the certificate file in the request. It is mandatory or we get an `invalid_client` error.

Comment: That's great news. Please consider to leave a snippet _how_ you did so and also as it's still fresh for you, a link to the part of the documentation that you'd deem coming closest for the (client?) certificate or how you were able to obtain it (the certificate). If it's a client certificate the error code is indeed misleading as it would not be the client but the authorization, but if you add a bit more to the answer this should become more clear.